# Open notification permission in settings app direct

Tags: ios, swift, settings, appsettings

I'm using this code to open my app specific settings in Apple settings app:

```
@IBAction func openSettings(sender: Any) {
    UIApplication.shared.openURL(URL(string: UIApplicationOpenSettingsURLString)!)
}
```

This directs to `Settings>[my_app_name]`, but it there a possibility to direct to `Settings>[my_app_name]>Notifications`?

Or is that not possible?

Till then,
David.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can only open the root of your own app's preferences. You can't open a sub-section directly

Comment: Will that result an app rejection? Code: `UIApplication.sharedApplication().openURL(NSURL(string: UIApplicationOpenSettingsURLString)!)`

Comment: No, that is allowed

Answer (score 0):

1. In your info.plist, add these code to this file:

`<key>CFBundleURLTypes</key>
    <array>
        <dict>
            <key>CFBundleTypeRole</key>
            <string>Editor</string>
            <key>CFBundleURLSchemes</key>
            <array>
                <string>prefs</string>
            </array>
        </dict>
</array>`

2. Then you can open your app settings in Apple settings app like this :

`let url = NSURL(string: "prefs:root=yourBundleId")
UIApplication.sharedApplication().openURL(url!)`

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but that was not the question.

Comment: No problem. You're not the first at this post. The others already deleted their post themselves.

Comment: well, I thought `prefs:root=yourBundleId&path=NOTIFICATION` may work, but I've tried it and failed.....  is it possible that the value of  key `path` is any  other words ?

Comment: I don't know. Perhaps it's not possible!?